# Why am I receiving Tableau error 6EA18A9E when adding a filter to a dashboard

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a working workbook but we're retro-fitting the new Tableau Relationship data model.  Am not sure that's a factor.

But on a dashboard with multiple worksheets when I try to add a Filter to the Dashboard I receive this error.  I've read about it but can't figure out what specifically happening.

My Desktop version is 2020.2.5 (20202.20.0818.0857) 64bit

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Error 6EA18A9E Occurs When Creating Empty Extract With Aggregate Data For Visible Dimensions Option In Tableau Desktop 2020.2 to 2020.3"
https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/Error-6EA18A9E-Occurs-When-Creating-Empty-Extract-With-Aggregate-Data-For-Visible-Dimensions-Option-In-Tableau-Desktop-2020-2-to-2020-3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and with the hint, that the error occures because of an empty extract I was searching through my workbook and found where Sheet A filters Sheet B. But with all fields from A this is way to much for B.
The solution was to deactivate the general filtering of sheet A and to create an individual action filter for sheet A and apply it on sheet B.

Hope that could help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact error, except for me it occurred when I was attempting to create a very simple animated timeline with Pages holding a list of years, and Columns holding a list of prices.

I have no idea if this is also what is causing your error when you add a filter, but I went into Format->Animations & turned off animations for the sheet and that fixed the error.